# Issue with Oracle Sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sequence having a huge difference of value around 2000 while using Merge..I initially had a cache of 20 while defining my sequence definition..later I redefined my sequence to

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "DMODS"."ORDER_SEQ" 
       MINVALUE 1 
       MAXVALUE 9999999999 
       INCREMENT 1               
       START WITH 1 
       NOCACHE 
       ORDER 
       NOCYCLE
```

I noticed that the value of the sequence is now varying by 2000 on an average for inserts/updates happening on the same day..can you please throw some light on this?

Comment: Can you show us your merge statement? It seems that sequence is incrementing for Updates also, not just for Inserts.

Comment: How does it matter if your sequences are not dense and have gap in values?

Comment: Hi San, Thank you ! Sure, my update does not have sequence value in place..in fact, I recreated the sequence and the insert alone has the ID column has the sequence column ..currently, there are 7 lakh records and now the sequence skips by 2000 records ..the value is close 1714960

Comment: Can NO Cache skip numbers ? I have a ROLLBACK transaction in my plsql code but these rows are inserted in my table ...I realize that these rows should be now incremented by 1 alone

Comment: Does Merge statement increment the sequence value NEXTVAL even if there is no sequence added to the update statement....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to quote Tom Kyte (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441)

*Sequences will never generate a gap free sequence of numbers.
If someone calls seq.nextval and doesn't insert the value somewhere (or does insert it 
and later rolls back their transaction) that number is GONE.
Sequences are database objects and may be aged out of the shared pool like everything 
else -- it doesn't take a database shutdown to produce a gap.
You should never count on a sequence generating anything even close to a gap free 
sequence of numbers.  They are a high speed, extremely scalable multi-user way to 
generate surrogate keys for a table.*

basically, it's not a problem, they do what they do. If you need a continuous sequence of numbers for your primary key you need to generate it yourself (max+1)

Dave